# Verifying the equivalence between the adjoint transformation and adjoint matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal, adjoint-operators

I'm trying to understand the relation between the adjoint as an operation $T^* $ and the adjoint as a matrix manipulation $T^\dagger$ (transposing and conjugating). So far, I understand that these definitions are equivalent only for linear transformation $T: V \to W$ where we use an orthonormal basis for both $V$ and $W$. However, I'm having trouble convincing myself that this actually works in the case of a nonstandard inner product.

For example, let us define a non-standard inner product by $\langle x, y \rangle = x' A y$. Using this inner product I can surely find some orthonormal basis $\alpha = (v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ of $V$ and $\beta = (w_1, \ldots, w_n)$ of $W$. If I'm not mistaken, however, for the adjoint 'operator matrix' $T^*$ we have $T^* = A^{-1} T^t A$, at least in the real case (see for example [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1320918/find-the-adjoint-of-this-non-standard-inner-product-space)). Clearly $T^* \neq T^{\dagger}$ even though it seems to me that all requirements are satisfied! What am I missing here?

Comment: Why do you expect the adjoint to be independent of the inner product that you're using?

Comment: Am I expecting that? I don't think I'm really understanding your question. I am aware that the adjoint can be expressed in terms of inner products with my orthogonal basis vectors. In case of an orthonormal basis this would simply be the adjoint matrix. My issue is that I don't see how this works out in practice.

Comment: Perhaps I can reformulate my question. Consider the example in the link of my question. As I see it, transformation $A$ _could_ correspond to a linear operation defined for a $V$ and $W$ with orthonormal bases. Yet, the adjoint is not the 'adjoint matrix'. What in that example ensures that the adjoint is not the adjoint matrix?

Comment: The nonstandard inner product you are defining is a pairing between different vector spaces $V$ and $W$, i.e. a map $V \times W \to \mathbb{C}$ - this is not an inner product, since it is a pairing between two spaces, rather than a pairing on a single space. Why don't you try changing the inner product on only $V$, and checking how the matrix of the adjoint of $T$ should change?